# Crear 2 autocomplete

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un problema, quiero crear dos autocomplete independientes uno para un input de pacientes y otro para funcionarios. El primero funciona sin problemas, pero al copiar el segundo cambiando los valores no autocompleta.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda. Saludos!

**Script en el index**

```
//Este funciona
  
     $(function() {  
 $( "#rut" ).autocomplete({
      source: "conexion.php",
      minLength: 1,

select: function( event, ui ) {
     $( "#nombre" ).val( ui.item.nombre_persona );
     $( "#apellido" ).val( ui.item.apellido_persona );

      }
     })
     });

//este No funciona

      $(function() {  
 $( "#run_f" ).autocomplete({
      source: "conexion.php",
      minLength: 2,

select: function( event, ui ) {
     $( "#nombre_f" ).val( ui.item.nombre_funcionario );
     $( "#apellido_f" ).val( ui.item.apellido_funcionario );
    }
     })
     });
```

**Consulta**

```
if(isset($_GET['term'])){
        $string = $_GET['term'];
    }else{

        $string = "";
}

            $result = mysqli_query ($conexion, "SELECT * FROM paciente where run like '%$string%'");


if ($result){
    $array = [];
    $array_respuesta=[];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        //print_r($row);
        $array['label'] =$row ['run'];
        $array['nombre_persona'] =$row ['nombre'];
        $array['apellido_persona'] =$row ['apellido'];
        array_push($array_respuesta, $array);   
    }
    echo json_encode($array_respuesta);

}

if(isset($_GET['term']))
    {
        $string2 = $_GET['term'];
    }else{

        $string2 = "";
    }


    $result2 = mysqli_query ($conexion, "SELECT * FROM funcionario where run_funcionario like '%$string2%'");

    if ($result2){
        $array2 = [];
        $array_respuesta2=[];
        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
            //print_r($row);
            $array2['run_f'] =$row2 ['run_funcionario'];
            $array2['nombre_funcionario'] =$row2 ['nombre'];
            $array2['apellido_funcionario'] =$row2 ['apellido'];
            array_push($array_respuesta2, $array2); 
        }
        echo json_encode($array_respuesta2);

    }
```

**input pacientes**

```
 <label for="rut">Run: </label>
 <input type="text" name="rut" id="rut">
 <br>
 <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
 <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
 <br>
 <label for="apellido">Apellido: </label>
 <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">
```

**Los input funcionario**

```
<label for="run_f">Podologa: </label>
<input type="text" name="run_f" id="run_f">
<br>
<label for="nombre_f">Nombre: </label>
<input type="text" name="nombre_f" id="nombre_f">
<br>
<label for="apellido_f">Apellido: </label>
<input type="text" name="apellido_f" id="apellido_f">
```

Comment: Hola, una duda, porque ocupas dos $(function() {?

Comment: Uno para el input de run funcionarios y el otro para el run pacientes.

Comment: Rectificó mi pregunta, entiendes para que sirve el function? Normalmente se ocupa solo uno, también se ocupa document ready de jQuery para que espere la carga de la página antes, creo que el error podría ir por esto, ya que al menos en sintaxis se ve bien, excepto por esto, y puedes tener N autocomplete

Comment: La verdad estoy recién aprendiendo a programar y me estaba guiando por videos tutoriales, investigare mas sobre el function. Saludos!